# Help me install my wireless drivers. (Cant seem to get it right with other solutions)

Tags: drivers, wireless

So it comes with 3 Linux folders inside which there is...

1.MT7601U Linux/DPO_MT7601U_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.4_20130913.tar.bz2

2.MT7610U Linux/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.tar.bz2

3.MT7612U Linux/MT7612U_DPO_LinuxSTA_3.0.0.1_20140718.tar.bz2

below is the instruction that is inside those .tar.bz2

PLEASE HELP ME INSTALL.

My skills are - I can open terminal, change directory using cd command and type things like sudo install etc. Thanks!

So I guess my wireless device info is 3.19.0-30-generic.. ??

> - README
>     *
> - Ralink Tech Inc.
> - - http://www.ralinktech.com
>       *

```
=======================================================================
ModelName:
===========
RT2870 Wireless Lan Linux Driver


=======================================================================
Driver lName:
===========
rt2870.o/rt2870.ko


=======================================================================
Supporting Kernel:
===================
linux kernel 2.4 and 2.6 series. 
Tested in Redhat 7.3 or later.


=======================================================================
Ralink Hardware:
===================
Ralink 802.11n Wireless LAN Card.


=======================================================================
Description:
=============
This is a linux device driver for Ralink RT2870 USB ABGN WLAN Card.


=======================================================================
Contents:
=============
Makefile            : Makefile
*.c                 : c files
*.h                 : header files


=======================================================================
Features:
==========
   This driver implements basic IEEE802.11. Infrastructure and adhoc mode with 
   open or shared or WPA-PSK or WPA2-PSK authentication method. 
   NONE, WEP, TKIP and AES encryption. 


=======================================================================
Build Instructions:  
====================

1> $tar -xvzf DPB_RT2870_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x.tgz
    go to "./DPB_RT2870_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x" directory.

2> In Makefile
     set the "MODE = STA" in Makefile and chose the TARGET to Linux by set "TARGET = LINUX"
     define the linux kernel source include file path LINUX_SRC
     modify to meet your need.

3> In os/linux/config.mk 
    define the GCC and LD of the target machine
    define the compiler flags CFLAGS
    modify to meet your need.
    ** Build for being controlled by NetworkManager or wpa_supplicant wext functions
       Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y'.
       => #>cd wpa_supplicant-x.x
       => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dwext -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d
    ** Build for being controlled by WpaSupplicant with Ralink Driver
       Please set 'HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y' and 'HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=n'.
       => #>cd wpa_supplicant-0.5.7
       => #>./wpa_supplicant -Dralink -ira0 -c wpa_supplicant.conf -d

4> $make
    # compile driver source code
    # To fix "error: too few arguments to function ¡¥iwe_stream_add_event"
      => $patch -i os/linux/sta_ioctl.c.patch os/linux/sta_ioctl.c

5> $cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat

6> load driver, go to "os/linux/" directory.
    #[kernel 2.4]
    #    $/sbin/insmod rt2870sta.o
    #    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 inet YOUR_IP up

    #[kernel 2.6]
    #    $/sbin/insmod rt2870sta.ko
    #    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 inet YOUR_IP up

7> unload driver    
    $/sbin/ifconfig ra0 down
    $/sbin/rmmod rt2870sta

=======================================================================
CONFIGURATION:  
====================
RT2870 driver can be configured via following interfaces, 
i.e. (i)"iwconfig" command, (ii)"iwpriv" command, (iii) configuration file

i)  iwconfig comes with kernel.  
ii) iwpriv usage, please refer to file "iwpriv_usage.txt" for details.
iii)modify configuration file "RT2870STA.dat" in /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat.

Configuration File : RT2870STA.dat
---------------------------------------
# Copy this file to /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
# This file is a binary file and will be read on loading rt.o module.
#
# Use "vi RT2870STA.dat" to modify settings according to your need.
# 
# 1.) set NetworkType to "Adhoc" for using Adhoc-mode, otherwise using Infrastructure
# 2.) set Channel to "0" for auto-select on Infrastructure mode
# 3.) set SSID for connecting to your Accss-point.
# 4.) AuthMode can be "WEPAUTO", "OPEN", "SHARED", "WPAPSK", "WPA2PSK", "WPANONE"
# 5.) EncrypType can be "NONE", "WEP", "TKIP", "AES"
# for more information refer to the Readme file.
# 
#The word of "Default" must not be removed
Default
CountryRegion=5
CountryRegionABand=7
CountryCode=
SSID=Dennis2860AP
NetworkType=Infra
WirelessMode=9
Channel=0
BeaconPeriod=100
TxPower=100
BGProtection=0
TxPreamble=0
RTSThreshold=2347
FragThreshold=2346
TxBurst=1
WmmCapable=0
AckPolicy=0;0;0;0
AuthMode=OPEN
EncrypType=NONE
WPAPSK=
DefaultKeyID=1
Key1Type=0
Key1Str=
Key2Type=0
Key2Str=
Key3Type=0
Key3Str=
Key4Type=0
Key4Str=
PSMode=CAM
FastRoaming=0
RoamThreshold=70
HT_RDG=1
HT_EXTCHA=0
HT_OpMode=1
HT_MpduDensity=4
HT_BW=1
HT_AutoBA=1
HT_BADecline=0
HT_AMSDU=0
HT_BAWinSize=64
HT_GI=1
HT_MCS=33
HT_MIMOPSMode=3
EthConvertMode=
EthCloneMac=
IEEE80211H=0
TGnWifiTest=0
WirelessEvent=0
MeshId=MESH
MeshAutoLink=1
MeshAuthMode=OPEN
MeshEncrypType=NONE
MeshWPAKEY=
MeshDefaultkey=1
MeshWEPKEY=
CarrierDetect=0

-----------------------------------------------
*NOTE:
    WMM parameters
            WmmCapable          Set it as 1 to turn on WMM Qos support              
            AckPolicy1~4        Ack policy which support normal Ack or no Ack
                                (AC_BK, AC_BE, AC_VI, AC_VO)        

    All WMM parameters do not support iwpriv command but ¡¥WmmCapable¡Š¡Š, 
    please store all parameter to RT2870STA.dat, and restart driver.    

-----------------------------------------------
syntax is 'Param'='Value' and describes below. 

@> CountryRegion=value                                 
    value
        0: use 1 ~ 11 Channel
        1: use 1 ~ 13 Channel
        2: use 10 ~ 11 Channel
        3: use 10 ~ 13 Channel
        4: use 14 Channel
        5: use 1 ~ 14 Channel
        6: use 3 ~ 9 Channel
        7: use 5 ~ 13 Channel
       31: use 1 ~ 14 Channel (ch1-11:active scan, ch12-14 passive scan)

@> CountryRegionABand=value                                 
    value   
        0: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 Channel
        1: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140 Channel
        2: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64 Channel
        3: use 52, 56, 60, 64, 149, 153, 157, 161 Channel
        4: use 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 Channel
        5: use 149, 153, 157, 161 Channel
        6: use 36, 40, 44, 48 Channel
        7: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 124, 128, 132, 136, 140, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 Channel
        8: use 52, 56, 60, 64 Channel
        9: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 132, 136, 140, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 Channel
       10: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 149, 153, 157, 161, 165 Channel
       11: use 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 100, 104, 108, 112, 116, 120, 149, 153, 157, 161 Channel

@> CountryCode=value
    value
        AG, AR, AW, AU, AT, BS, BB, BM, BR, BE, BG, CA, KY, CL, CN, CO, CR, CY, CZ, DK, DO, EC, SV, FI, FR, DE, 
        GR, GU, GT, HT, HN, HK, HU, IS, IN, ID, IE, IL, IT, JP, JO, LV, LI, LT, LU, MY, MT, MA, MX, NL, NZ, NO,
        PE, PT, PL, RO, RU, SA, CS, SG, SK, SI, ZA, KR, ES, SE, CH, TW, TR, GB, UA, AE, US, VE
        "" => using default setting: 2.4 G - ch 1~11; 5G - ch 52~64, 100~140, 149~165

@> SSID=value                   
    value
        0~z, 1~32 ascii characters.

@> WirelessMode=value
    value   
        0: legacy 11b/g mixed 
        1: legacy 11B only 
        2: legacy 11A only         //Not support in RfIcType=1(id=RFIC_5225) and RfIcType=2(id=RFIC_5325)
        3: legacy 11a/b/g mixed     //Not support in RfIcType=1(id=RFIC_5225) and RfIcType=2(id=RFIC_5325)
        4: legacy 11G only
        5: 11ABGN mixed
        6: 11N only
        7: 11GN mixed
        8: 11AN mixed
        9: 11BGN mixed
       10: 11AGN mixed  

@> Channel=value
    value
        depends on CountryRegion or CountryRegionABand

@> BGProtection=value
    value
        0: Auto 
        1: Always on 
        2: Always off

@> TxPreamble=value
    value
        0:Preamble Long
        1:Preamble Short 
        2:Auto

@> RTSThreshold=value
    value
        1~2347                                                       

@> FragThreshold=value
    value           
        256~2346

@> TxBurst=value
    value
        0: Disable
        1: Enable

@> NetworkType=value                
    value 
        Infra: infrastructure mode
        Adhoc: adhoc mode

@> AuthMode=value
    value
        OPEN        For open system 
        SHARED      For shared key system   
        WEPAUTO     Auto switch between OPEN and SHARED
        WPAPSK      For WPA pre-shared key  (Infra)
        WPA2PSK     For WPA2 pre-shared key (Infra)
        WPANONE     For WPA pre-shared key  (Adhoc)
        WPA         Use WPA-Supplicant
        WPA2        Use WPA-Supplicant

@> EncrypType=value
    value
        NONE        For AuthMode=OPEN                    
        WEP         For AuthMode=OPEN or AuthMode=SHARED 
        TKIP        For AuthMode=WPAPSK or WPA2PSK                    
        AES         For AuthMode=WPAPSK or WPA2PSK                     

@> DefaultKeyID=value
    value
        1~4

@> Key1=value
    Key2=value
    Key3=value
    Key4=value
    value
        10 or 26 hexadecimal characters eg: 012345678
        5 or 13 ascii characters eg: passd
    (usage : "iwpriv" only)     

@> Key1Type=vaule
    Key2Type=value
    Key3Type=vaule
    Key4Type=vaule
    value
        0   hexadecimal type
        1   assic type
    (usage : reading profile only)

@> Key1Str=value
    Key2Str=value
    Key3Str=vaule
    Key4Str=vaule
    value
        10 or 26 characters (key type=0)
        5 or 13 characters  (key type=1)
    (usage : reading profile only)  

@> WPAPSK=value                 
    value
        8~63 ASCII          or 
        64 HEX characters

@> WmmCapable=value
    value
        0: Disable WMM
        1: Enable WMM

@> PSMode=value
    value
        CAM             Constantly Awake Mode
        Max_PSP         Max Power Savings
        Fast_PSP        Power Save Mode

@> FastRoaming=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> RoamThreshold=value
    value
        Positive Interger(dBm)

@> HT_RDG=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> HT_EXTCHA=value (Extended Channel Switch Announcement)
    value
        0               Below
        1               Above

@> HT_OpMode=value
    value
        0               HT mixed format
        1               HT greenfield format

@> HT_MpduDensity=value
    value (based on 802.11n D2.0)
        0: no restriction
        1: 1/4 £gs
        2: 1/2 £gs
        3: 1 £gs
        4: 2 £gs
        5: 4 £gs
        6: 8 £gs
        7: 16 £gs

@> HT_BW=value
    value
        0               20MHz
        1               40MHz

@> HT_AutoBA=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> HT_BADecline
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled <Reject BA request from AP>

@> HT_AMSDU=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> HT_BAWinSize=value
    value
        1 ~ 64

@> HT_GI=value
    value
        0               long GI
        1               short GI

@> HT_MCS=value
    value
        0 ~ 15
        33: auto

@> HT_MIMOPSMode=value
    value (based on 802.11n D2.0)
        0               Static SM Power Save Mode
        1               Dynamic SM Power Save Mode
        2               Reserved
        3               SM enabled
    (not fully support yet)

@> EthConvertMode=value
    value
        dongle
        clone
        hybrid

@> EthCloneMac=value
    value
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

@> IEEE80211H=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> TGnWifiTest=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> WirelessEvent=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled <send custom wireless event>

@> MeshId=value
    value
        Length 1~32 ascii characters

@> MeshAutoLink=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

@> MeshAuthMode=value
    value
        OPEN        For open system 
        WPANONE     For WPA pre-shared key  (Adhoc)

@> MeshEncrypType=value
    value
        NONE        For MeshAuthMode=OPEN                    
        WEP         For MeshAuthMode=OPEN
        TKIP        For MeshAuthMode=WPANONE
        AES         For MeshAuthMode=WPANONE

@> MeshWPAKEY=value
    value
        8~63 ASCII          or 
        64 HEX characters

@> MeshDefaultkey=value
    value
        1~4

@> MeshWEPKEY=value
    value
        10 or 26 characters
        5 or 13 characters

@> CarrierDetect=value
    value
        0               Disabled
        1               Enabled

MORE INFORMATION
=================================================================================
If you want for rt2870 driver to auto-load at boot time:
A) choose ra0 for first RT2870 WLAN card, ra1 for second RT2870 WLAN card, etc.

B) create(edit) 'ifcfg-ra0' file in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/,      
   edit( or add the line) in /etc/modules.conf:
       alias ra0 rt2870sta

C) edit(create) the file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ra0  
   DEVICE='ra0'
   ONBOOT='yes'     


NOTE:
   if you use dhcp, add this line too .
    BOOTPROTO='dhcp'

*D) To ease the Default Gateway setting, 
    add the line
    GATEWAY=x.x.x.x   
    in /etc/sysconfig/network

=======================================================================
Dongle/Clone Features:
======================
A) Dongle mode: 
    Provides a 1-to-N MAC address mapping mechanism such that more than one PC behind the STA 
    can transparently connect to the AP.

B) Clone mode:
    Provides a 1-to-1 MAC address mapping mechanism. 
    STA can use own MAC as SA MAC or 
            use user desired MAC as SA MAC or
            use source MAC of first packet coming from wired device as SA MAC.
    NOTE: In this mode, only the PC who own the specified MAC can connect to the AP.


C) Hybrid mode(Dongle+Clone):
    Provides a 1-to-N MAC address mapping mechanism such that more than one PC behind the STA 
    can transparently connect to the AP.
    STA can use own MAC as SA MAC or 
            use user desired MAC as SA MAC or
            use source MAC of first packet coming from wired device as SA MAC.

D) Please refer to "Config STA to link as dongle mode..." in iwpriv_usage.txt for releated commands.
```

Comment: Which of the MT76XXU models do you have?

Comment: All of them. It comes with all the three.

Comment: No, what is the model/make/serial number of the wireless card?
You may and should only install one of these drivers!
That's why the first instruction (`$tar -xvzf DPB_RT2870_Linux_STA_x.x.x.x.tgz`) has those Xs, because you have to figure out which of the drivers is the correct one.

Comment: The only thing i can find on the pakage is, S0b754-SDL013826326...any idea where to look? I have installed successfully on my windows.

Comment: And the model is tb-0135B

Comment: Please insert the device in the USB slot, open a terminal and run: `lsusb`. Next, edit your question to add the details of your wireless device.  We also need to see the result of: `uname -r`

Comment: I type lsusb.. Then one result is 148f:7601 ralink technology, corp.. Then i type uname -r ...then the result is 3.19.0-30-generic

Comment: I don't understand the other thred..they are experts..please i am a noob..a simple step by step instructions is required.

Comment: I can open terminal thats all...please HELP!

Comment: And which is my device verison?...

Comment: Connect to the internet by wire and run the commands one by one.

Comment: The one that have the most votes by chili555??

Comment: Can you please join me in chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51952/chat-with-andrew-twirling-and-chili555

Comment: @chili555 Did you solve this?